# I need to merge/join several lines of code into one

Tags: html, wordpress, function, dreamweaver

This may seem like a silly question, but I am looking for a way to merge/join several lines of code into one.  I've been creating popups for a game and when i make a table that has 76 rows at minimum, the code has returns making the code go down 100's of lines.  Once it is populated, it then has to be put into one line to work as a function in wordpress functions.  I use Dreamweaver CC to create it then port it over to wordpress.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: JavaScript? Search for js minify online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a text editor like Notepad++, you can do a Find/Replace with extended characters or regular expression.

Find `\r\n` (carriage return/line feed) and replace with  (nothing/empty string).

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Same could be done with a PHP script on the server:

```
<?php
$multilines = <<<EOL
all
your
multiple
lines
here
EOL;

$oneline = str_replace( "\r\n", '', $multilines );
// if you want to get fancy you can remove indentation too using this instead:
$oneline = str_replace( array( "\r", "\n", "\t" ), '', $multilines );
echo $oneline;
```

Comment: Thanks!  That did it.